# Packing a string to contain null-bytes

Tags: ruby

I want to pack a string containing `"00000000"`.

If i do `"00000000".to_a.pack('H*')` I get an error

> in 'system': string contains null byte (ArgumentError)

I need to send this as a hex string to a microprocessor. A sample could be `0x81 0x00 0x00 0x21`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
input = "A000B0"
output = []
until input.empty?
  output << input[0, 2].to_i(16)
  input = input[2..-1]
end
puts output.pack('C*').inspect # => "\xA0\x00\xB0"
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a `pack` directive for null bytes: `x`.

```
>> ["a", "b"].pack("HxH") #=> "\xA0\x00\xB0"
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't see that. However my hex string is taken from a user input, hence I don't know when to use null-bytes and when not to. A user might write `0x81 0x00 0x00 0x00` or any other combination on the last three bytes.